# In SQL Server delete duplicates of date leaving only one record as per date

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I have data like this:

```
ID      uid     UUID           downtime   updated_time               received time            status
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4794    6501    61075024966012    60      2019-12-27 06:00:02.813    2019-12-23 05:07:46.120    0
4332    0354    61075026156000    1440    2019-12-27 06:00:02.813    2019-12-23 17:49:56.393    0
4333    0354    61075026156000    1440    2019-12-27 06:00:02.813    2019-12-23 17:49:56.393    0
4334    0354    61075026156000    1440    2019-12-27 06:00:02.813    2019-12-23 17:49:56.393    0
4335    0354    61075026156000    1440    2019-12-27 06:00:02.813    2019-12-23 17:49:56.393    0
4336    0354    61075026156000    1440    2019-12-27 06:00:02.813    2019-12-23 17:49:56.393    0
4337    0354    61075026156000    1440    2019-12-27 06:00:02.813    2019-12-23 17:49:56.393    0
4338    0354    61075026156000    1440    2019-12-27 06:00:02.813    2019-12-23 17:49:56.393    0
4345    0355    61075026156001    1440    2019-12-27 07:00:02.813    2019-12-23 19:49:56.393    0
4346    0355    61075026156001    1440    2019-12-27 07:00:02.813    2019-12-23 19:49:56.393    0
4347    0355    61075026156001    1440    2019-12-27 07:00:02.813    2019-12-23 19:49:56.393    0
4348    0355    61075026156001    1440    2019-12-27 07:00:02.813    2019-12-23 19:49:56.393    0
4355    0358    61075026156221    23      2019-12-27 07:00:02.813    2019-12-23 19:49:56.393    0
4365    0358    61075026156221    35      2019-12-29 07:00:02.813    2019-12-23 19:49:56.393    0
```

In the above records I want to delete the records if they have the same UUID and update_time (as there is a duplicate data insertion).

For example `UUID = 61075026156000` has the same `update_time` 7 times; I want to delete 6 records leaving only one. Like this I want to delete for all UUID's if they have the same `update_time` - leaving only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `ROW_NUMBER()` like this:

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by uuid, updated_time order by id) rn
  from tablename  
)
delete from cte
where rn > 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3a557c84ff9830ca52ee2f873f9e2e02).
Results:

```
>   ID |  uid | UUID           | downtime | updated_time        | recieved time       | status
> ---: | ---: | :------------- | -------: | :------------------ | :------------------ | -----:
> 4794 | 6501 | 61075024966012 |       60 | 27/12/2019 06:00:02 | 23/12/2019 05:07:46 |      0
> 4332 |  354 | 61075026156000 |     1440 | 27/12/2019 06:00:02 | 23/12/2019 17:49:56 |      0
> 4345 |  355 | 61075026156001 |     1440 | 27/12/2019 07:00:02 | 23/12/2019 19:49:56 |      0
> 4355 |  358 | 61075026156221 |       23 | 27/12/2019 07:00:02 | 23/12/2019 19:49:56 |      0
> 4365 |  358 | 61075026156221 |       35 | 29/12/2019 07:00:02 | 23/12/2019 19:49:56 |      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select min(id), uid, uuid, downtime, updated_time
from t
group by uid, uuid, downtime, updated_time;
```

This gets the duplicates across the four columns -- which appears to be what you want.  You can also limit to just the two columns you mention:

```
select min(id), min(uid), uuid, min(downtime), updated_time
from t
group by uid, uuid, downtime, updated_time;
```

Or use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
             row_number() over (partition by uuid, updatedtime order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using EXISTS

```
  delete t
  from tablename t
  where exists (select 1 
                from tablename tt 
                where tt.uuid = t.uuid and tt.updatedtime = t.updatedtime and tt.id < t.id)
```